# SQL Query Update Calculation using 2 Tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 2 tables:  GBPAUD_TA and GBPAUD_DATA

The GBPAUD_DATA table sample is:

```
Date_Time                 Low        High        Open        _1m_21 
('2020-07-01 19:05',    '1.8036',   '1.8038',   '1.8035',   '1.8031'),
('2020-07-01 19:06',    '1.8035',   '1.8036',   '1.8034',   '1.8031'),
('2020-07-01 19:07',    '1.8035',   '1.8037',   '1.8035',   '1.8032'),
('2020-07-01 19:08',    '1.8037',   '1.8039',   '1.8037',   '1.8032'),
('2020-07-01 19:09',    '1.8038',   '1.804',    '1.8037',   '1.8033'),
('2020-07-01 19:10',    '1.8038',   '1.804',    '1.8038',   '1.8033'),
('2020-07-01 19:11',    '1.804',    '1.8043',   '1.804',    '1.8034'),
('2020-07-01 19:12',    '1.804',    '1.8041',   '1.8038',   '1.8034'),
('2020-07-01 19:13',    '1.8039',   '1.8039',   '1.8037',   '1.8035'),
('2020-07-01 19:14',    '1.8038',   '1.804',    '1.8037',   '1.8035'),
('2020-07-01 19:15',    '1.804',    '1.804',    '1.8036',   '1.8036'),
('2020-07-01 19:16',    '1.8039',   '1.8041',   '1.8038',   '1.8036'),
('2020-07-01 19:17',    '1.8039',   '1.804',    '1.8036',   '1.8036'),
('2020-07-01 19:18',    '1.8037',   '1.8039',   '1.8034',   '1.8037'),
('2020-07-01 19:19',    '1.8034',   '1.8036',   '1.8032',   '1.8036'),
('2020-07-01 19:20',    '1.8034',   '1.8035',   '1.8033',   '1.8036'),
('2020-07-01 19:21',    '1.8034',   '1.8036',   '1.8033',   '1.8036'),
('2020-07-01 19:22',    '1.8033',   '1.8034',   '1.803',    '1.8036');
```

The GBPAUD_TA table sample is:

```
Open_Date          New_Closing_Time    Action  _1m_L1_Time 
'2020-07-01 19:05', '2020-07-05 21:58', 'Buy'   NULL
```

Here is my code thus far:

```
UPDATE GBPAUD_TA AS t1
            SET _1m_L1_Time = COALESCE(
              (
                SELECT 
                  MIN(
                    CASE t1.Action
                      WHEN 'Buy' THEN CASE WHEN (t2._1m_21 >= t2.Low AND t2._1m_21 < t2.Open) THEN t2.Date_Time END
                      WHEN 'Sell' THEN CASE WHEN (t2._1m_21 <= t2.High AND t2._1m_21 > t2.Open) THEN t2.Date_Time END
                    END
                  )
                FROM GBPAUD_DATA t2  
                WHERE t2.Date_Time >= t1.Open_Date AND t2.Date_Time <= t1.New_Closing_Time
              ),
              t1._1m_L1_Time
            )
```

The logic is: I start looking at Date_Time in between the Open_Date and New_Closing_Time.  I am looking for when the _1m_21 is less than Open and Greater than equal to the Low, for an Action type of "buy".  If it is a "sell", then I am looking for when the _1m_21 is Greater than Open and less than or equal to the High.  When the above conditions are met, then it updates GBPAUD_TA's _1m_L1_Time field with the Date_Time of row the result that met the criteria in the DATA table.

The above sample data, it should return `2020-7-1 19:15`.

When I run the below query in DB Browser, it says affected "2132 rows affected", but when I Write the Changes and Browse the Data, nothing has updated in this column _1m_L1_Time.

I have put the sample data in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=0584a737c8f485c1721e40d781e8e75d)

I have double checked the Table names and column names.  They are accurate.  I don't know why it is not updating properly.  Can anyone help?  I appreciate it!

Comment: I can't find any issue in your code. see the result of `SELECT * FROM GBPAUD_DATA t2 where t2._1m_21 >= t2.Low AND t2._1m_21 < t2.Open` it is returning 0 records then why would it update your table `GBPAUD_TA`?

Comment: Sorry, my fault.  I confused the data last night.  I have updated the correct data (and updated the demo as well).  So if I manually check, I can find that 2020-07-1 19:15 meets the criteria.  But the query output is NULL.

Comment: Also, I have written the same code in Python against the loaded dataframe from the GBPAUD_DATA table.  And it actually returns results for the same data while SQL Query does not.  So I wanted to figure out why that is.

Comment: This condition: *when the _1m_21 is less than Open and Greater than equal to the Low* is not satisfied in any row of GBPAUD_DATA in your sample data. Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=dfbf4ddb612102fb6030ffbc507fd2ab

Comment: No. When I manually go through the data the output should be 2020-7-1 19:15, as it does meet the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

in this case

```
CASE t1.Action
   WHEN 'Buy' THEN CASE WHEN (t2._1m_21 >= t2.Low AND t2._1m_21 < t2.Open) THEN t2.Date_Time END
   WHEN 'Sell' THEN CASE WHEN (t2._1m_21 <= t2.High AND t2._1m_21 > t2.Open) THEN t2.Date_Time END
END
```

it return null, that why your result is null. and if you want to see it's null or not you just run this query to check it

```
select * from GBPAUD_DATA t2  where t2._1m_21 >= t2.Low AND t2._1m_21 < t2.Open
```

summaries, your data in "GBPAUD_DATA" is not have a condition to meet your case that  why the columns "_1m_L1_Time" is null

[demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=22471bbace6012aed904f2b4e58af373)

Comment: Sorry, my fault.  I confused the data last night.  I have updated the correct data (and updated the demo as well).  So if I manually check, I can find that 2020-07-1 19:15 meets the criteria.  But the query output is NULL.

Comment: Also, I have written the same code in Python against the loaded dataframe from the GBPAUD_DATA table.  And it actually returns results for the same data while SQL Query does not.  So I wanted to figure out why that is.

Comment: i try to add some condition data to meets and it working, could you try to visit it via this link
[link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=22471bbace6012aed904f2b4e58af373)

Comment: No.  When I manually go through the data the output should be ```2020-7-1 19:15```.  Your output in DBFiddle is ```2020-07-01 22:27```.

Comment: in this infomation
`Date_Time,                Low,         High,         Open,     _1m_21
('2020-07-01 19:15', '1.804', '1.804', '1.8036', '1.8036')` 
your condition is 
`CASE WHEN (t2._1m_21 >= t2.Low AND t2._1m_21 < t2.Open)`
it not meet the condition because _1m_21 (1.8036) is less then Low (1.804) and 
_1m_21 (1.8036) is not less then Open (1.8036) 
that why the result is not show